# Symfony 3.4: How can I get full country name in twig

Tags: php, symfony, controller, symfony-forms, country-codes

```
$builder->add('nationality', CountryType::class, array('preferred_choices' => array('ET'),'required' => true,'attr' => array('style' => 'width:300px')))
```

It display the full name in the combobox, but it saves the initials (FR for FRANCE, UG for Uganda, ET for Ethiopia etc..)

The following is the source code of the page and it shows that the values are the initials.

```
</div><option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AL">Albania</option><option value="DZ">Algeria</option><option value="AS">American Samoa</option><option value="AD">Andorra</option><option value="AO">Angola</option><option value="AI">Anguilla</option><option value="AQ">Antarctica</option><option value="AG">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option><option value="AR">Argentina</option><option value="AM">Armenia</option><option value="AW">Aruba</option>
```

When I read from the database {{ student.nationality }}, I get the initials

How can I make the CountryType class saves the full name of the counties?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the CountryType class, it will *always* save the value using the 2-character standard country code. This is standard database practice to store only what you need and nothing more to reference a value. What you'll need to do is to do a lookup in your template of what that code means. I've never coded with Symfony or Twig, but I found this in the documentation:

See: http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/intl.html#country-names

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;

\Locale::setDefault('en');

$countries = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames();
// => array('AF' => 'Afghanistan', ...)

$country = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName('GB');
// => 'United Kingdom'
```

Comment: When i added this component it says Maximum execution time.Tried multiple times in different way, every time same result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @sholsinger.

Here is the solution

```
public function showAction(Student $student)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($student);
    $Country = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName($student->getNationality());
    return $this->render('student/show.html.twig', array(
        'student' => $student,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        'Nationalite' => $Country,
    ));
}
```

It prints the full name of of the country in the show.html.twig using {{ Nationalite }}